# Android RecyclerView Adapter: Passing normal clicks and menu clicks over the same activity

Tags: java, android

I am unsure about my approach here. As you can see, I want to send normal clicks and 2 different menu item clicks back to the underlying activity over an interface. Now I wonder if it is bad practice to send it over the same interface. I couldn't find an answer online. Also, any suggestions about what to change here?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}

@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                mListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select Action");
        MenuItem doWhatever = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Do whatever");
        MenuItem delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Delete");

        doWhatever.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case 1:
                        mListener.onWhatEverClick(position);
                        return true;
                    case 2:
                        mListener.onDeleteClick(position);
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);

    void onWhatEverClick(int position);

    void onDeleteClick(int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
}
```

Comment: i guess you used this answer as a template https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292712/android-custom-event-listener

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to read that code. I think some part is missing as I can't figure out what's going on.

However when you look at [SOLID principles](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-s-o-l-i-d-principle-in-android-a90947f57cf0), you'll find that the `public interface OnItemClickListener` you created probably violates the [I — The Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)](https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-s-o-l-i-d-principle-in-android-a90947f57cf0), exactly as `TextWatcher` does.

For more on this, see also Donn Felker's article [*I is for the Interface Segregation Principle*](https://academy.realm.io/posts/donn-felker-solid-part-4/).